# How to use MAX with show all data on SQL

Tags: sql, max

Sorry for my bad english, I need help using MAX query that would show the entire data record.
Example data :
Table A -
Student_name -
course_name -
Score

```
Name    Course          Score
Aldo || Mathematics  || 90
Aldo || Physics      || 85
Aldi || Mathematics  || 60
Aldi || Physics      || 50
```

Desired result
I want to show max score on every course name but with show all data on table

Example:

```
Name    Course          Score   Max Course
Aldo || Mathematics  || 90    || 90
Aldo || Physics      || 85    || 85
Aldi || Mathematics  || 60    || 90
Aldi || Physics      || 50    || 85
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in SQL to achieve results.
The below query will extract all records in the table as well as the max of the score.

```sql
    select name,
       course,
       score,
       max(score) over (partition by course order by score desc) as max_course
    from {table}
```

Comment: @Aldo Julianto said:
Thank you so much for your help, but i got some error when i execute that query, there is an error:

select name, course, score, 
max(score) over (partition by course) as maxcourse
from score

results :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(PARTITION BY 'course')
from score LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2